# Create and manage backups on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, wbadmin

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server with partition size larger than 2TB that I have to backup.
Since WBAdmin doesn't work on partition size larger than 2TB, do you have any tool, idea or recommendation to do so? What do you use if you have ran into a similar situation?

Comment: Have you considered distributing data between smaller volumes? 
Full backups will take a significant amount of time to complete.

Comment: "What do you use if you have ran into a similar situation?" --- 3rd party backup software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current server backup only supports a volume smaller than 2TB as the source

You can make a small reg-hack to overcome the volume issue.

To remove the 2TB limit in the backup wizard.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Server\Server Backup
QWORD MaxVolumeSize = n
N is some number larger than your volume size. 2TB is 0x1FDFFE00000 or 2190431223808 bytes
```

**The total data itself cannot be over 2TB within the volume.**

Otherwise like many, would use alternative third party tools.

Comment: I'm doing this on Server 2008 (not R2), I hoped this would be similar enough.  But if my registry does not have the "Windows Server" entry am I okay to create it?  I don't see why not, just don't want to break anything.  Also, I've check the registry of my R2 server and I do not have the "Windows Server" folder either.